# How do i compute for checkbox field in django form?

Tags: django, django-forms

Iam failing to understand some misbehavior in my code,

Here i define `radio` and `check boxes` within template form instead of a django form,

```
<form method="post" action=".">
      {% csrf_token %}
   {% for optionalitem in optionalcategory.optional_items.all %}
     <input type="radio" value="{{optionalitem.id}}" name="option">{{optionalitem.name}}
  {% endfor %}
  {%for topping in toppingcategory.topping.all %}
     <input type="checkbox" value="{{topping.id}}" name="topping">{{topping.name}}
  {% endfor%}
   ........
  </form>
```

form validation,

```
    .....
    final_form = form(request.POST)
            if final_form.is_valid():
                order.add_to_order(request,a)
                ....
        else:
            final_form = partial_order_item_form()
        ....
```

i have my model that makes use of the post data generated by the form;

```
class OrderItem(SmartModel):
    ......
    option = models.ForeignKey(Optional_Item,null=True,blank=True)
    topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping,null=True, blank=True)
```

then i create the `OrderItem object`  using postdata from the form above,

```
def add_to_order(request,obj):  
    postdata = request.POST.copy()
    op = postdata.get('option',False)
    optional_item = None
    if op: 
        optional_item = get_object_or_404(Optional_Item, pk=op)
    toppings_checked = postdata.get('topping',None)
    toppings = None
    if toppings_checked: 
        toppings = get_object_or_404(Topping, pk=toppings_checked)
    .....
    if not item_in_orders:
        # creat and save a new order item
        anon_user = User.objects.get(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID) 
        oi=OrderItem.objects.create(item=i,
                                          topping = toppings,
                                          option = optional_item,
                                          created_by=anon_user,
                                          modified_by=anon_user)
        oi.save()
```

my problem arises from the this function as i try to compute a subtotal for an `OrderItem`

```
def order_subtotal(request):        
    .....
    for order_item in order_items:
        if order_item.item.price:
            order_total += order_item.item.price * order_item.quantity
        elif order_item.option:
            order_total += order_item.option.price * order_item.quantity
        elif order_item.topping:
            order_total += order_item.topping.price * order_item.quantity
    return order_total
```

when i compute the subtotal for an `option` it works out just fine but it does not for the `topping`.
I am not understanding why.I prefer a detailed answer but also short ones are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace your `elif` with regular `if`'s.

Right now, if an `order_item` has an option, then you will not look at the toppings, as you'll branch out of the `if` block immediately!

(As a matter of fact, you won't look at the options nor toppings if it has a price).

You should do:

```
  for order_item in order_items:
    if order_item.item.price:
        order_total += order_item.item.price * order_item.quantity
    if order_item.option:
        order_total += order_item.option.price * order_item.quantity
    if order_item.topping:
        order_total += order_item.topping.price * order_item.quantity
```

Comment: @SuziemacTani Then you might want to debug what flow your code going through by adding print or logging statements.

Comment: you are right, using pdb, i found the issue to be with naming, am going to mark your anwser right because i think its better than what i was doing.